# Italics removal in latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am using TeXstudio to generate my pdf.

I have a statement which has a few symbols and numbers. I tried typing it within the dollar symbol ($). After compiling and building it, the entire text seems to be in italics and with no spaces in between them. How to avoid this? My text is the following.

The curve of 1.5 Gr provides a good fit of the data down to Z=16.0 by adopting a A(C-D)=0.03 and (V-H)=11.1\pm 0.3.

In case I try this without any math symbols, then it shows an error.

Comment: Future question on (La)TeX should be asked on [tex.se].

Answer (score 0):

Try putting only the maths parts between the dollar signs.

```
The curve of $1.5 Gr$ provides a good fit of the data down to $Z=16.0$ by adopting a $A(C-D)=0.03$ and $(V-H)=11.1 \pm 0.3$.
```

http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/Dt4wxs0M

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to type text inside math mode, then use `\text{<yourtext>}`. For example, 
`$\text{This is test} 4.05V$`.